# Как реализовать простой функционал входа на WP?

Tags: wordpress

есть простая задача
Сайт на WP, и кнопка вход. Регистрации не будет ибо, доступы даются вручную, и будет лишь одни доступы.
Если пользователь ввел их правильно перезагружается страница и появляется блок ( + боди выдается класс)
При выходе( Кнопка выхода) Блок скрываем( даже удаляем из хтмл) И боди убирается класс
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше поступать в решение данной задачи

Comment: А стандартная фича "пароль на пост" - не подходит?

Comment: AJAX-авторизация и больше добавить нечего.